# Android pattern generation algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, android

I have a random integer (6 digits like 568215) and I want to generate a valid path for the Android pattern from that.
Suppose that:
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
As you know for example 4 - 1 - 3 - 6 is invalid because line 1 - 3 passes through key 2 which we can't jump to 3, or for another example we can't select a node twice, so as an example 546512 is invalid because 5 is duplicated and many other paths like these.
So this paths aren't valid:
(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 34, 37, 38, 39, 46, 49, 67, 79)
I have written a function that works well, but its problem is that I don't know how to avoid generate duplicated nodes.

> Here is what I've tried:

```
$notValidWalk = array(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 34, 37, 38, 39, 46, 49, 67, 79);
$key = 562458;

function makeValidWalks($key, $notValidWalk)
{
    $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));

    $section1 = false;
    $section2 = false;
    $section3 = false;
    $section4 = false;
    $section5 = false;


    while ($section1 == false) {
        if ($array[0] == 9 && $array[1] == 9) {
            $array[0] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if ($array[0] == 0) {
            $array[0] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (in_array($array[0] . $array[1], $notValidWalk) || in_array($array[1] . $array[0], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section1 = false;
            $tmp = ($array[0] . $array[1]) + 1;
            $key = $tmp . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (!in_array($array[0] . $array[1], $notValidWalk) && !in_array($array[1] . $array[0], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section1 = true;
        }
    }



    while ($section2 == false) {
        if ($array[1] == 9 && $array[2] == 9) {
            $array[1] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if ($array[1] == 0) {
            $array[1] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (in_array($array[1] . $array[2], $notValidWalk) || in_array($array[2] . $array[1], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section2 = false;
            $tmp = ($array[1] . $array[2]) + 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $tmp . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (!in_array($array[1] . $array[2], $notValidWalk) && !in_array($array[2] . $array[1], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section2 = true;
        }
    }


    while ($section3 == false) {
        if ($array[2] == 9 && $array[3] == 9) {
            $array[2] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if ($array[2] == 0) {
            $array[2] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (in_array($array[2] . $array[3], $notValidWalk) || in_array($array[3] . $array[2], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section3 = false;
            $tmp = ($array[2] . $array[3]) + 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $tmp . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (!in_array($array[2] . $array[3], $notValidWalk) && !in_array($array[3] . $array[2], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section3 = true;
        }
    }


    while ($section4 == false) {
        if ($array[3] == 9 && $array[4] == 9) {
            $array[3] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if ($array[3] == 0) {
            $array[3] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (in_array($array[3] . $array[4], $notValidWalk) || in_array($array[4] . $array[3], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section4 = false;
            $tmp = ($array[3] . $array[4]) + 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $tmp . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (!in_array($array[3] . $array[4], $notValidWalk) && !in_array($array[4] . $array[3], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section4 = true;
        }
    }


    while ($section5 == false) {
        if ($array[4] == 9 && $array[5] == 9) {
            $array[4] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if ($array[4] == 0) {
            $array[4] = 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (in_array($array[4] . $array[5], $notValidWalk) || in_array($array[5] . $array[4], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section5 = false;
            $tmp = ($array[4] . $array[5]) + 1;
            $key = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $tmp;
            $array = array_map('intval', str_split($key));
        }
        if (!in_array($array[4] . $array[5], $notValidWalk) && !in_array($array[5] . $array[4], $notValidWalk)) {
            $section5 = true;
        }
    }
    return $array = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4] . $array[5];

}
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a valid walk or validate if a walk is valid or not?

Comment: I want to generate valid walks base of random 6digits number.

Comment: So you want it to generate a valid walk based on the 6 digits you pass to the function?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: The walk will not be necessarily 6 digits right? For example, if you pass it `546512`, what do you expect as a result?

Comment: Yes, that's right. but I expect that the final key to be at least 4 digits because I think less than 4 nodes are easy to guess.so for `546512` I expect that it changes to a number that follows rules for the android pattern and doesn't have duplicated digits.(my function works well but its algorithm generates duplicated digits in some cases.)